# How to format long and large tables in a thesis?

Tags: tables, formatting, best-practices

In my master's thesis I have a lot of tables, large and long;
what's the best practice to fit them ?

It would be fine split the longer table in multiple pages?

what about the larger ones?

any advice will be appreciated

UPDATE

here an example of a large table

```
\begin{table}[H] 
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|r|}
\hline HTTP Date & Time zone & Time shift & Timestamp \\
\hline Tue, 02 Jun 2015 20:33:31 GMT & America/Chicago & -6 & June 2nd 2015, 22:19:31.929 \\
\hline Sun, 14 Jun 2015 11:33:46 GMT & America/Denver & -7 & June 14th 2015, 13:19:07.193 \\
\hline Sun, 14 Jun 2015 11:34:01 GMT & America/Los\_Angeles & -8 & June 14th 2015, 13:19:21.755 \\
\hline Sun, 14 Jun 2015 11:33:46 GMT & America/New\_York & -5 & June 14th 2015, 13:19:07.417 \\
\hline Sun, 14 Jun 2015 12:19:18 GMT & America/Phoenix & -7 & June 14th 2015, 14:04:38.980 \\
\hline Sun, 14 Jun 2015 11:33:59 GMT & America/Toronto & -5 & June 14th 2015, 13:19:19.881 \\
\hline Fri, 12 Jun 2015 05:53:03 GMT & Asia/Shanghai & 8 & June 12th 2015, 07:38:31.238 \\
\hline Sun, 14 Jun 2015 11:33:56 GMT & Europe/Amsterdam & 1 & June 14th 2015, 13:19:17.290 \\
...
        \hline      
    \end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico, question updated, however the biggest issue is if it is right to split a table in multiple pages

Comment: Is rotate table for 90 degree an acceptable option?

Comment: @Zarko, it could be, I must find out how do it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ltablex` package, which loads both `tabularx` and `longtable`. What makes the table a little too wide is the head of the 3th column, which I circumvent with a `\makebox[0pt]` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, ltablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=-2.0, table-number-alignment=center}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{\,}X@{\enspace}l r SX@{\enspace}l@{\,}}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{HTTP Date}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Time zone}
  & {\makebox[0pt]{Time shift}}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Timestamp} \\
  \midrule
  Tue, 02 Jun 2015, & 20:33:31 GMT
    & America/Chicago & -6 & June 2nd 2015, & 22:19:31.92 \\
  Sun, 14 Jun 2015, & 11:33:46 GMT
    & America/Denver & -7 & June 14th 2015, & 13:19:07.193 \\
  % \hline
  Sun, 14 Jun 2015, & 11:34:01 GMT
    & America/Los\_Angeles & -8 & June 14th 2015, & 13:19:21.755 \\
  Sun, 14 Jun 2015, & 11:33:46 GMT
    & America/New\_York & -5 & June 14th 2015, & 13:19:07.417 \\
  Sun, 14 Jun 2015, & 12:19:18 GMT
    & America/Phoenix & -7 & June 14th 2015, & 14:04:38.980 \\
  Sun, 14 Jun 2015, & 11:33:59 GMT
    & America/Toronto & -5 & June 14th 2015, & 13:19:19.881 \\
  % \hline
  Fri, 12 Jun 2015, & 05:53:03 GMT
    & Asia/Shanghai & 8 & June 12th 2015, & 07:38:31.238 \\
  Sun, 14 Jun 2015, & 11:33:56 GMT
    & Europe/Amsterdam & 1 & June 14th 2015, & 13:19:17.290 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I very liked your solution for third column :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, rotating table for 90 degrees is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{showframe}

    \begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[p]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ r@{\ }l r S r@{\ }l }
        \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{HTTP Date} 
    &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{Time zone}
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{Time shift} 
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Timestamp}                           \\
        \midrule
Tue, 02 Jun 2015,  &   20:33:31 GMT 
    &   America/Chicago         & -6    &   June 2nd 2015,  &   22:19:31.92  \\
Sun, 14 Jun 2015,  &   11:33:46 GMT 
    &   America/Denver          & -7    &   June 14th 2015,  &   13:19:07.193 \\
%        \hline 
Sun, 14 Jun 2015,  &   11:34:01 GMT 
    &   America/Los\_Angeles    & -8    &   June 14th 2015,  &   13:19:21.755 \\
Sun, 14 Jun 2015,  &   11:33:46 GMT 
    &   America/New\_York       & -5    &   June 14th 2015,  &   13:19:07.417 \\
Sun, 14 Jun 2015,  &   12:19:18 GMT 
    &   America/Phoenix         & -7    &   June 14th 2015,  &   14:04:38.980 \\
Sun, 14 Jun 2015,  &   11:33:59 GMT 
    &   America/Toronto         & -5    &   June 14th 2015,  &   13:19:19.881 \\
%        \hline 
Fri, 12 Jun 2015,  &   05:53:03 GMT 
    &   Asia/Shanghai           & 8     &   June 12th 2015,  &   07:38:31.238 \\
Sun, 14 Jun 2015,  &   11:33:56 GMT 
    &   Europe/Amsterdam        & 1     &   June 14th 2015,  &   13:19:17.290 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
    \end{document}
```

but then the page looks very empty:

[image]

For above image I slightly reformat your table (introduced two additional column). In it I add `siunitx` package for better formatting "time shift, and `booktabs` for nicer rulers. In table, as you can see, I omit vertical lines. Maybe the solution in which you split text in the long cells into shorter two lines will be better solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[margin=30mm,showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X r S X }
        \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{HTTP Date} 
    &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{Time zone}
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{Time shift} 
            &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{Timestamp}                   \\
        \midrule
Tue, 02 Jun 2015,\newline  
20:33:31 GMT 
    &   America/Chicago & -6    &   June 2nd 2015,\newline   
                                    22:19:31.92                 \\
Sun, 14 Jun 2015,\newline   
11:33:46 GMT
    &   America/Denver          & -7    &   June 14th 2015,\newline
                                            13:19:07.193        \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

For above MWE I add two packages: `geometry` (because I haven't a clue, how your page is set up) by which I defined page, and `tabularx`, which fit table into text width and make multi line cells possible. Option `showframe` in `geometry` package serves only to show text borders. In normal circumstances it should be omit.

If you like to extend this table over more page, than you need select a table environment, which support this. One possible solution is in Bernard answer.

Comment: option `showframe` for geometry would avoid loading showframe.

Comment: @Bernard, thank you for this information. I use geometry occasionally (only in answers/questions for SE) so I'm still not very familiar with it. I will correct my answer.